# R's read.csv() breaks data to fit the console's width

Tags: r, read.csv

I use `read.csv()` to import data to R. The problem is that R fits the console's width and I get all my data in several levels. I need all my data together and be able to scroll through it with the scroll bar. Is it possible?

Comment: Use Rstudio and View(your_data) command...you will get your data in a spreadsheet like tab.

Comment: Hi, you can modify the width of the consol to fit your screen. To get the width of your screen try **options()$width**, and to modify it type **options(width = my_value)**.

Comment: glimpse(mydata) from the dplyr package is good at this, but of course you don't the all the observations... you can't have both!

Answer (score 0):

As Miha mentioned in a comment [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/) is a great option for this. It's free to download and makes lots of standard data exploration a lot easier than the console.  Also, if your data is small enough that you would want to scroll through it a simple text editor should do the trick.  [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) is my favorite.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I installed RStudio. Still using read.csv() and RStudio breaks the data into lines while displaying it. Do i do something wrong? I just need standart column-row/wide data format.

Comment: The problem was with a separator. Once it was specified, it run properly.